# json_decode JSON string with serialized array as value

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON string that contains a php serialized array as one of its value.

```
[options] => [{"id":"3", "choices":"a:2:{i:0;s:3:"yes";i:1;s:2:"no";}", "correct_answer":"yes"}]
```

I am trying to json_decode this [options] field and extract the "choices" field.

```
$optionArrJSON = json_decode($list['options'], true);
```

But I am getting `NULL`.

I presume it is because of the serialized array as value.

How can I decode this string, or just fetch that "`choices`" key-value somehow?

Comment: I tried to encode JSON using serialise data but it looks like {"id":"3","choices":"a:2:{i:0;s:3:\"yes\";i:1;s:2:\"no\";}"} and I am able to fetch the data.

Comment: @BhavinSolanki can you post it as an answer?

Comment: First of all, you have to provide a code of serializing. Then we can suggest improvements to that.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will help ..

```
$list['options'] = json_encode('[{"id":"3", "choices":"a:2:{i:0;s:3:"yes";i:1;s:2:"no";}", "correct_answer":"yes"}]'); 
echo json_decode($list['options'],true);
```